# iOS6 appstore: URL to search for apps corresponding to defined keywords on Appstore?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, app-store

Up to now (before iOS 6), it was possible to display all the apps corresponding do defined keywords on the appstore. The URL to use was the following one:

http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?WOURLEncoding=ISO8859_1&lang=1&output=lm&media=software&term=SEARCH_TERM1+SEARCH_TERM2+SEARCH_TERM3

This URL doens't work any more on iOS6.

Is there any URL to perform a search on iOS 6 appstore ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

http://ax.search.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?media=software&term=SEARCH_TERMS

Comment: Great ! Works on iOS 6 :) Thanks !